# how to create a css for laptop, is it max-width 1024 or 1600px?

Tags: css

I am confused here because I read that we should use a max-width of 1024px for a laptop but on my chrome extension break point, this looks okay but when a friend of mine tested my site, it looks way off! I just need more of a general advice here then coding help so won't add any codes yet...

Comment: For laptop the screen size is vary.. so u can change the max-width to 1280.. because all the laptop screens are start with 1280.. so u can add this in 1280 too

Comment: Laptops with HiDPI are of 1440px screen size & MDIP are of 1280px.

Comment: that explains why.... so if I changed it to 1280, it should look fine on a laptop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This article on screen sizes & media queries is up to date and looks quite useful >>> https://ricostacruz.com/til/css-media-query-breakpoints

Comment: also, for most breakpoints extension, they never did provide any laptop breakpoint and I find this odd

Comment: I tried using those suggested breakpoints but it still looks way off on another person's laptop and I understand that they do vary a lot

Comment: Are u clear with my prev comment?